# What's the regular expression to replace (., space, -, ) in a string using Labview

Tags: labview

I am trying to replace some unnecessary characters in a string in LabView. For example in the following string, `"he llo-hOW-are.You?"` I want to replace space, <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> with an Underscore <kbd>_</kbd>.

The output shall be `"he_llo_hoW_are_You?"`

I tried `"[\ \.\-]"` and many more things but nothing seem to work for a regular expression.

I am using Search and Replace function and I am putting the Regular expression in the Search String field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you make sure to right click the function and check the Regular Expression option? The function won't work with regexes otherwise (as the help for it says).

This seems to work just fine here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the Regular Expression in the "Search and Replace String" right click menu.

[image]

It should work with the regular expression you are trying to use. Or you can use [\ .-] in the Regex as well.

Answer (score 0):

This logic will apply all special Characters.

[image]